# Why is Excel not accommodating my VBA Module?

Tags: excel, vba

VBA module in excel is a good way to automate some of the hefty work. I have been trying to assign a macro to a button but am unable to do so. A dialog box appears asking me to save it in another format. Which format is that??

Comment: 1. What did you try on your own?  2. You should also add a picture to show us what you want accomplishing. I have an idea, but not sure I understood. If the same elements of column A:A is not unique, you should show it. 3. Is the content of columns B:B **exactly as you show it in the picture**? 4. Do you want the processing result in the same format/pattern? 5. And the screen-capture is not for as.  We do not need it...

Comment: Still alive? What do you mean by **the total number of variations**? Does the same element in A:A column have different keys? I mean if the first one has in col B:B "{key1:value1, key2:value2}", will the next have different keys (key3...)? If not, should all found keys be concatenated (comma separated) even if "key1:value1" will be repeated many times?

Comment: I have edited the post for clarity. There is a separate dictionary for each item, so it does not matter whether the elements/keys are distinct/unique or not. The goal is to get the number of dictionary elements for each item inserted in Col C. That's that. @FaneDuru

Comment: So you only want **counting** so named dictionary elements... I will post a pice of code in one, two minutes.

Comment: Can the keys or values contain commas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub testCountKeys()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, arr, arrC
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet                 'use here your necessary sheet
    lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row 
    arr = sh.Range("B1:B" & lastR).value 'put column B:B in an array (to run faster)
    ReDim arrC(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'redim the array to receive the count
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)            'iterate between the array elements
        arrC(i, 1) = UBound(Split(arr(i, 1), ",")) + 1 'count by splitting on ", "
    Next i
    'drop the array content at once:
    sh.Range("C1").Resize(lastR, 1).value = arrC
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! That's a brilliant approach! Although it does not give me the exact number of dictionary items, but I think your code will help me find my way through this problem! Thank you so very much! @FaneDuru

Comment: @rafayk330: It does not return **the exact number of dictionary items**. **only if there are inconsistences in your B:B range data**. I mean, it is possible to not have all the time ", " separator. The space after comma. I will adapt the code to return only based on comma...

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a way. The extension of the saved file is `.xlsm` so using this, I can enjoy assigning macros to buttons. Cheers! Thanks for your support, everyone!